# Computing precision in case of multi-label classification

Tags: multilabel-classification, metric

When evaluating a multi-label model for precision by averaging the precision of each sample, would it be appropriate to a) ignore those samples where no prediction is being made? Or is it more appropriate to b) consider precision as 0 for such samples.

Eg:

Ground-Truth: `[[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1]]`

Prediction: `[[1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]]`

Precision by averaging over each sample:

a) `(1 + 0.5) / 2`?   OR

b) `(1 + 0 + 0.5) / 3`?

Answer (score 1):

Precision and recall are defined for a single binary classification problem, they cannot be used directly for either multi-class or multi-label classification. However one can use micro-average or macro-average precision (or recall), this is the standard way to evaluate with multiple classes.

Apparently you're using macro-average and your example should be interpreted like this:

```
                class 1    class 2    class 3
Ground-Truth: [[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1]]
Prediction:   [[1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
```

With precision being calculated for class 1.

If so you have a mistake for class 3, the precision is also 1, not 0.5.

To answer your question: in the case of class 2, precision is not zero, it's undefined (NaN) since there's no instance predicted positive. Strictly speaking, the macro-average is also undefined because one value is NaN. But if you must calculate the macro-average value, it makes much more sense to discard class 2 as in option (a) rather than count its precision as zero as in option (b), which is incorrect.